# Model selection for sequence classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-mining

## Searching for best (highest accuracy) model to classify a sequence of values

#### Some observations so far from manually classifying many of these:

- Each sequence will have 500-5k pieces
- Each piece can take on ~200 different values
- Ordering is important.  (e.g. [...,4,4,5,...] can be very different from [...,5,4,4,...])
- Frequency is important (seeing the value '9' many times has meaning)
- Neighbors are important (e.g. [...,7,3,7,...] significantly different than [..,7,..,3,..,7,..]
- Most of the sequence will be dominated by the same value (e.g. 80% of the entries in the sequence will be wither a 2 or 6)
- Entries that are close in value are not really related (e.g. 15 is not "similar to 14, but stronger")

#### What I've considered

- **Text classification**.  If I consider each entry in the sequence to be a character or a word, it seems like this is just a DSL that needs to be classified.

  - The snag here is most advice/state of the art text classifiers I've been referred to are heavily embedding dependent, which I'm told is less effective in the dataset I've described above.
- **CNN with the values as a picture**. This sounded promising because CNN is cognizant of ordering, neighbors, counts, all those good things.

  - Feedback here told me to avoid this because CNN is heavily dependent on edge detection which would fail here

At some point I'm just going to just start diving in and see what shakes out but wanted to see if there are any suggestions I'm missing.  Very new to this field.

Followup Questions:

> "What is a sequence?"

The list of past states of a player in a board game.

> "What is a piece?"

Just one value in the sequence.  An item.

> "What is the goal of this analysis?"

To categorize an unlabeled sequence in one of two labels.

Comment: Context would probably help. What are these sequences? What are the pieces? What is the goal of your analysis?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @PeterFlom.  Let me add some clarifications in the main question.

Comment: @PeterFlom I've made some updates.

To help me in future questions, can you let me know why it's important to know what a sequence represents?

To me it seems like the model is determined by the structure of data, and the structure of data is determined by the real life scenario it represents.  But in this question I provided the structure of data already so it's not clear to me why we're still dependent on the real-life scenario to answer this.

Comment: When you seek a comparison or an extreme, such as a "best model," there is no way to determine the answer without knowing how "best" ought to be evaluated.  Typically, people are unable to articulate that in a sufficiently quantitative way, so we rely on understanding the context, motivation, and objectives that underlie the problem, as well as knowing what the data represent and how they are measured.

Comment: It's always important to know the context of a data analysis problem because a solution that might make sense in one context might not make sense in another.

Comment: @PeterFlom got it, I'll keep that in mind going forward.

Is there anything else I'm missing for context that could be helpful here?  Can we look into taking this off hold?